# Optimal way to read out JSON from MongoDB into a Scalatra API

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, scalatra, casbah

I have a pre-formatted JSON blob stored as a string in MongoDB as a field in one of collections. Currently in my Scalatra based API, I have a before filter that renders all of my responses with a JSON content type. An example of how I return the content looks like the following:

```
   get ("/boxscore", operation(getBoxscore)) {
        val game_id:Int = params.getOrElse("game_id", "3145").toInt
        val mongoColl = mongoDb.apply("boxscores")
        val q: DBObject = MongoDBObject("game_id" -> game_id)
        val res = mongoColl.findOne(q)
        res match {
            case Some(j) => JSON.parseFull(j("json_body").toString) 
            case None => NotFound("Requested document could not be found.")
        }
    }
```

Now this certainly does work. It doesn't seem the "Scala" way of doing things and I feel like this can be optimized. The worrisome part to me is when I add a caching layer and a cache does not hit that I am spending additional CPU time on re-parsing a String I already formatted as JSON in MongoDB:

```
JSON.parseFull(j("json_body").toString)
```

I have to take the result from findOne(), run .toString on it, then re-parse it into JSON afterwards. Is there a more optimal route? Since the JSON is already stored as a String in MongoDB, I'm guessing a serializer / case class isn't the right solution here. Of course I can just leave what's here - but I'd like to learn if there's a way that would be more Scala-like and CPU friendly going forward.

Comment: As JSON is just a string - can't you just return the string from your view?

Answer (score 0):

There is the option to extend Scalatra's render pipeline with handling for MongoDB classes. The following two routes act as an example. They return a [`MongoCursor`](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCursor) and a [`DBObject`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBObject.html) as result. We are going to convert those to a string.

```
get("/") {
  mongoColl.find
}

get("/:key/:value") {
  val q = MongoDBObject(params("key") -> params("value"))
  mongoColl.findOne(q) match {
    case Some(x) => x
    case None => halt(404)
  }
}
```

In order to handle the types we need to define a partial function which takes care of the conversion and sets the appropriate content type.

There are two cases, the first one handles a `DBObject`. The content type is set to "application/json" and the object is converted to a string by calling the `toString` method. The second case handles a `MongoCursor`. Since it implements `TraversableOnce` the `map` function can be used.

```
def renderMongo = {
  case dbo: DBObject =>
    contentType = "application/json"
    dbo.toString

  case xs: TraversableOnce[_] => // handles a MongoCursor, be aware of type erasure here
    contentType = "application/json"
    val ls = xs map (x => x.toString) mkString(",")
    "[" + ls + "]"

}: RenderPipeline
```

(Note the following type definition: `type RenderPipeline = PartialFunction[Any, Any]`)

Now the method needs to get hooked in. After a HTTP call has been handled the result is forwarded to the render pipeline for further conversion. Custom handling can be added by overriding the `renderPipeline` method from `ScalatraBase`. With the following definition the `renderMongo` function is called first:

```
override protected def renderPipeline = renderMongo orElse super.renderPipeline
```

This is a basic approach to handle MongoDB types. There are other options as well, for example by making use of [`json4s-mongo`](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/tree/master/mongo).

[Here](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-website-examples/blob/master/2.2/persistence/scalatra-casbah-example/src/main/scala/org/scalatra/example/json_conversion.scala) is the previous code in a working sample project.